How to handle grid overlap?
I want to use a thick curve to cut an object. The specific steps are as follows:

Merge two objects and select a mesh with curves
Enter Edit Mode and use Face > Intersect (Boolean)
For the Solver select Fast
Use Select > Select Loop > Select Loop Inner-Region
Delete selected face

After that, I can get two border lines. However, due to the curve being too thick, there is a cross at some corners, as shown in the red box. My ultimate goal is to delete the mesh wrapped by the curve and re-bridge it myself to achieve edge retopology. How can I avoid this cross, or is there a better way to achieve my goal?


